# How can you make a Windows USB HDD Modify All for All Users

Tags: windows, permissions, filesystems, hard-drive, ntfs

I use a USB HDD a lot between lots of different Windows Boxes.

What I find after a while is that there get to be lots of different Permission on the files in some cases stopping me looking at files or removing them. They want Admin rights or even sometimes you need to put the disk back into the original machine with the original user.

This is a right pain.

Is there away of making the disk have Modify All for All Users and making this the default for all files on the disk.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include Everyone pseudouser in Security list for and give him full access right. In the advanced menu check both "replace.." and "inherit..." checkboxes, than press "OK". You can also can change owner of the root folder in advanced options.

Comment: I have just done this on the disk in question and it has stopped a lot of the problems but there are still files which it will not let me take ownership off.

Comment: I found that the items had Deny Write permission set. After removing them - it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Take everything off the drive.

Format it as FAT32 (or exFAT if you'll only be plugging into Vista and newer boxes), that way anyone can modify any file without any permissions worries.

Comment: I have used this before and if you start off with a FAT32 drive it works well but there are times where an NTFS volume is needed.